# Is the set of polynomials of odd degree dense in $\mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b])$?

Tags: analysis, polynomials, dense-subspaces

Let $$E=\{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}\,x^{2k+1}\, | \, n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}$$ be the set of polynomials of odd degree in each term defined on $[1,2]$.
(a) Show that $E$ is not closed in $\mathcal{C}^{0}([1,2])$, where $\mathcal{C}^{0}([1,2])$ is the space of continuous function from $[1,2]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with sup norm.
(b) Is $E$ dense in $\mathcal{C}^{0}([1,2])$?

Here's my proof:
(a) Consider the partial sum of the taylor series of $\sin(x)$, then every partial sum are in $E$ obviously, i.e., there is a sequence $\{f_{i}(x)\}$ of $E$, However, the limit of the sequence $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not in $E$. This shows that $E$ is not closed.
(b) I've tried to prove it using Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, but the theorem only states the polynomial space $\mathbb{R}[x]$ dense in $\mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b])$, i.e., $$\forall \epsilon >0 \mbox{ and } \forall f(x)\in\mathcal{C}^{0}([a,b]), \exists \, p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x] \mbox{ s.t. } \|f(x)-p(x)\|_{\infty}<\epsilon.$$
Thus I want to use triangle inequality to find a polynomial with odd degree $p'(x)$ such that $\|p(x)-p'(x)\|<\epsilon$, but it is impossible since not every polynomial function is the odd function. If you control the distance of two polynomials when $x>0$, another side must have large distance. So I'm stuck, and I guess the answer is NOT.

Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: $E$ is not the set of polynomials of odd degree. $1+x^{2}+x^{3}$ is also of odd degree.

Comment: @geetha290krm odd degree " in each terms ".

Comment: Hint: If $p \in E$ then $p(x)/x = q(x^2)$ for some other polynomial $q$.

Comment: An interesting side-note to this question is the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) (often in the literature referred to as the Müntz theorem; I think the addition of Szász to the *name* of the theorem is relatively recent), which is a much stronger but still easily stated result. Obviously, you're not intended to assume the Müntz–Szász theorem, or to prove it and then conclude what is being asked from it, but I thought it worth mentioning the Müntz–Szász theorem for math appreciation purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is true for $[1,2]$.

First let $f$ be  smooth. Then we can approximate $f'$ uniformly on $[1,2]$ by a polynomial with only even powers of $x$. This is an easy consequence of Stone-Wiertsrass Theorem.  Now integrate to finish the proof. The general case follows by first apllying Wierstrass Theorem and then applying above argument.

EDIT: As pointed out by Severin Schraven, there will be an extra  constant term in this approach. As suggested in that comment, we can approximate the continuous function $\frac {f(x)} x$ by a polynomial with only even powers of $x$ and multiply by $x$. $E$ is dense for any interval $[a,b]$ which does not contain $0$.

In the case of intervals containing $0$, only functions vanishing at $0$ belong to the closure of $E$.

Comment: How do you ensure that you can approximate the constant term? It is not in $E$, so after integration one cannot just absorb it. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I guess you want to approximate $f(x)/x$ by polynomials of only even powers (works as we are away from the origin) and then multiply through with $x$ to get the result.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you very much for pointing out the mistake and suggesting an alternative. If you would like to post your answer please let me know and I would gladly delete my answer.

Comment: Please use that alternative. It is essentially your idea up to a twist. Also it would be nice if you could remark that it fails for any interval which contains zero (as all odd polynomials vanish at zero).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks again.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks a lot! Now I get it.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven And also thank you very much. You guys are really talented!